# Select menu with option doesn't recognize page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twig

I've a problem with a "select" in a mobile version of my site. This is the code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectGift">
    {% for category in rewards_categories %}
        <option id="{{category.tag}}" class=" BarCategory Bar{{category.tag}}" value="/xxxx/{{ category.id }}/{{ category.categoryName}}">
            {{category.categoryName}}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

As you can see i'm using Twig extension in my template. The problem is that when I change option the redirect works but will not change the active list item , it is always the first. And I don't know how can I do this..

This is my JS code:

```
$('#selectGift').bind('change', function () {
    var url = $(this).val();
    window.location = url;
    $(this).find('option:selected').addClass('active'); 
});
```

I also have two Twig variables i can use:

{{category.id}} in which i have the id of the category that apper in the list;

{{currentIdCategory}} in which i have the id of the current category page displayed;

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No `option` will ever be `selected` with the code that you are currently using. You need to pass the `selected` value to your template and check in your loop if the loop's current value matches the selected one and set the attribute `selected` if so

Comment: i have two Twig variables:{{category.id}} in which i have the id of the category that apper in the list, {{currentIdCategory}} in which i have the id of the current category page displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the current selected category  (as seen in comments):

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectGift">
    {% for category in rewards_categories %}
        <option id="{{category.tag}}" class=" BarCategory Bar{{category.tag}}" value="/xxxx/{{ category.id }}/{{ category.categoryName}}" {% if category.id == currentIdCategory|default(-1) %} selected{% endif %}>
            {{category.categoryName}}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```